# Большие буквы в прозвищах/псевдонимах

Tags: орфография

Если прозвище (псевдоним) человека состоит из нескольких слов, нужно ли каждое слово писать с большой буквы? Правильно писать "Чёрная стрела" или "Чёрная Стрела" (о прозвище/псевдониме)?

Answer (score 2):

Справочник Розенталя на Грамоте:

> § 95. Пишутся с прописной буквы имена, отчества, фамилии, псевдонимы,
>   прозвища, например: Александр Сергеевич Пушкин, Павел Иванович
>   Мельников (Андрей Печерский), Макбет, Иван Грозный, Сципион Старший,
>   Иван Кольцо, Соловей Разбойник, Pичард Львиное Сердце, Владимир
>   Красное Солнышко, Петр Первый (Петр I) .

Так что  Чёрная Стрела и без кавычек.